# How does verify purchase was signed correctly using developer's public key, at server side will make the app more secure?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Based on the in-app purchase code example at https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive_v2/shared-module/src/main/java/com/example/billingmodule/billing/BillingManager.java#L369

```
/**
 * Verifies that the purchase was signed correctly for this developer's public key.
 * <p>Note: It's strongly recommended to perform such check on your backend since hackers can
 * replace this method with "constant true" if they decompile/rebuild your app.
 * </p>
 */
private boolean verifyValidSignature(String signedData, String signature) {
```

I was wondering, how does perform such verification at server side will make the app more secure?

As, I imagine the hacker can simply

1. Force `verifyValidSignature` return true, without even having to communicate with server side.
2. I believe in app code, there will be functions like `isThisPaidUser()`. The hacker can simply make those functions return true.

May I know, how does **"perform such check on your backend"** is better?

Comment: Well its a continuous battle and there is no one solution. But you can always identify how the hacker has modified your code and learn from it and make sure future versions can't be modified that way. But mostly it's not worth the time unless lot many people are using your cracked build. If you're happy with your profits, just let the cracked software people enjoy :)
Having said that, the best hackers live by the code of ethics where your products won't be hacked unless you're doing something really terrible. But yeah, anything can be hacked and bypassed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variety of languages for this.
first, avoid use of Boolean variable, what the server returns can be a string "whatever", here is an example:

```
<?php 
// get data param
$data = $_GET['data'];

// get signature param
$signature = $_GET['signature'];

// get key
$key_64 = "";



$key =  "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n".
    chunk_split($key_64, 64,"\n").
    '-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';
//using PHP to create an RSA key
$key = openssl_get_publickey($key);


// state whether signature is okay or not
$ok = openssl_verify($data, base64_decode($signature), $key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
if ($ok == 1) {
    echo "good";
} elseif ($ok == 0) {
    echo "bad";
} else {
    die ("fault, error checking signature");
}

// free the key from memory
openssl_free_key($key);

?>
```

In the client side you can use a tiny lib [StringCare/AndroidLibrary](https://github.com/StringCare/AndroidLibrary)
for encrypt the string and compare the result of the server:

```
result.toString().equals("ecryptedstring")
```

If the attacker uses apktool,jadx or others to see the code he will not be able to decrypt the string in an easy way, the lib use the java Cipher an generate X509Certificate for you string, StringCare needs the final fingerprint of you app for this, but has .equals can be replaced by equals (true) you need a better obfuscation maybe using xor with malleability with a nested try-catch and test it with the popular libs has use the hacker.

A more sophisticate system is send the purchase.sku, purchase.purchaseToken to the server of google api using [in-app-purchase npm lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/in-app-purchase) that help validating subscriptions and others.